# How can I rename all files with one extension to a different extension recursively

Tags: bash, find, rename, recursive

Say I have a folder:

```
/
/a.bub
/v.bub
/dr.bub
/catpictures
/catpictures/or.bub
/catpictures/on.bub
```

How can I format a script to change each of these to `.aaa`.

Here is what I've got, although it seems like a wrong approach:

```
find -type f -name "*.bub" -print0 -exec mv
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `find` and `xargs`:

```
$ find some_folder -type f -name "*.bub" | 
    sed "s/\.bub$//" | 
    xargs -I% mv -iv %.bub %.aaa
`some_folder/a.bub' -> `some_folder/a.aaa'
`some_folder/v.bub' -> `some_folder/v.aaa'
`some_folder/dr.bub' -> `some_folder/dr.aaa'
`some_folder/catpictures/or.bub' -> `some_folder/catpictures/or.aaa'
`some_folder/catpictures/on.bub' -> `some_folder/catpictures/on.aaa'
```

... which you could generalise to a bash function:

```
$ extmv () {
    find "${1}" -type f -name "*.${2}" | 
    sed "s/\.${2}$//" | 
    xargs -I% mv -iv "%.${2}" "%.${3}"
}
```

... which you'd use like this:

```
$ extmv some_folder/ bub aaa
```

Answer (score 11):

The simplest method is using bash itself:

```
for f in *.bub; do mv "$f" "${f/.bub/.aaa}"; done
```

As very correctly pointed out by @ZeroPiraeus and @HaukeLaging this is not recursive. You can make it recursive by activating the [`globstar`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) option:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.bub; do mv "$f" "${f/.bub/.aaa}"; done
```

For older versions of bash, use `find`:

```
find -type f -name "*.bub" | while read f; do 
  mv "$f" "${f/.bub/.aaa}";
done
```

Comment: Your "simplest method using bash" doesn't work recursively as per the question ...

Comment: That doesn't work for subdirectories. You need `**` instead. In the second version the "" are missing. And `sed` is not necessary. bash can do that itself: `mv "$f" "${f%.bub}.bub"`

Comment: That doesn't work either, as written. I think you're looking for `shopt -s globstar` followed by `for f in **/*.bub; do mv -iv "$f" "${f/.bub/.aaa}"; done` (which does work to arbitrary depths of recursion, and doesn't require the `*.bub` you included).

Comment: @terdon If `globstar` is set then ** goes arbitrarily deep. One could say that `shopt -s globstar` should be added to your `**` answer.

Comment: @terdon have you actually set the `globstar` option as mentioned by myself and @HaukeLaging in the comments above? If not, `**` is the same thing as `*` (which would explain your result).

Comment: @terdon you'll still get false positives with your answer (`**/*bub` should be `**/*.bub`), and as mentioned, the preceding `*.bub` is redundant.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus and there I go, feeling like an idiot again. Yes, I figured that out just before reading your comment. Thanks to both you and HaukeLaging. Answer edited, should work as advertised now.

Comment: @HaukeLaging thanks, everything clear now.

Comment: @terdon: the `find` version is a lot safer, since it won't fail on directories whose names end `.bub`.